# Android-Get DOB from years,months and days

Tags: android

I want to display **DOB** from given years, months and days.

I got **years**, but not able to calculate month and days. Please help me.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: hi if we give the age of person as 0 years,10months and 12 days then the DOB should be 07-12-2014.So by calculating given values,it should display the exact date of birth.Please tell me the logic.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give logic to my question.Thanks in advance

Comment: Using Datepicker ???

Comment: without datepicker.i got birth year by subtracting current year and given year value.but im nt able to get month and day.please help me.

Comment: okay .What you tried ?

Comment: i got birth year by subtracting current year and given year value.but im nt able to get month and day.please help me.I have to display date of birth

Comment: `String[] userDobArray=userDobOBJ.split("/");
                    if(userDobArray.length==3)
                    {
                        int intYear=Integer.parseInt(userDobArray[0]);
                        int intmonth=Integer.parseInt(userDobArray[1]);
                        int intDay=Integer.parseInt(userDobArray[2]);`

Comment: if u dont mind please explain

Comment: okay .whtas your DOB prints ?? give data

Comment: but i have to get dob by giving persons years,months and days.i dont know what logic to write for birth month and date from given months and days.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set particular date to the date picker,Use below code to update date in date picker.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2013, 05, 23);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

    int xxday = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int xxmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int xxyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    datepicker.init(xxyear, xxmonth, xxday, null);
```

If you want to get the date from the DatePicker,Try this

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
 int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
 int year = datePicker.getYear();
```

**Difference between two dates:**

```
String toyBornTime = "2014-06-18 12:56:50";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {

        Date oldDate = dateFormat.parse(toyBornTime);
        System.out.println(oldDate);

        Date currentDate = new Date();

        long diff = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
        long seconds = diff / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        long hours = minutes / 60;
        long days = hours / 24;

        if (oldDate.before(currentDate)) {

            Log.e("oldDate", "is previous date");
            Log.e("Difference: ", " seconds: " + seconds + " minutes: " + minutes
                    + " hours: " + hours + " days: " + days);

        }

        // Log.e("toyBornTime", "" + toyBornTime);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you want Month(s) and Year(s).

```
Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
Calendar endCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
endCalendar.setTime(endDate);

int diffYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int diffMonth = diffYear * 12 + endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: i have to get dob by giving persons years,months and days.got the birth year by subtracting current year and given years.i dont know what logic to write for birth month and date from given months and days.